# Hash map to find a pair that add to a given sum

Tags: c++, arrays, hash

I'm trying to learn how to use hash maps in C++ and am having trouble getting a randomly generated array into a hash map with ints for keys and vectors as the values(for repeated values in the array). I haven't gotten to coding the sum yet, as I want to make sure I can input the array into the hashmap first.

When I output the hash map with my display function I get

```
        Total size: 1
 Index in H  Number
key: 0  values: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

The array I create has 15 values ranging from 1-10, so there are repeats, hence the need for vectors. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong, so any kind of guidance would be welcome.

```
#include <iostream>   
#include <time.h>     
#include <fstream>
#include <map>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>

void display(std::map <int, std::vector<int> > hash);

int main(){
    srand (time(NULL));
    int temp;
    int tempCount = 1;
    int count = 0;
    int number;
    int k = 10; //sum for pairs in an array

//create array for testing
    int size = 15;
    int foo[size] = {};
    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i){
        foo[i] = ((double)rand() * (10 - 1) / (double)RAND_MAX + 1);
    }
    //print array:
        for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i){
        std::cout << foo[i] << std::endl;
    }

//Find pairs in an array whose sum is equal to ten using hash map    
    std::map <int, std::vector<int> > hash;
    const std::pair<int, int> pairs[size];
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        std::make_pair(pairs[foo[i]] , i);
    }

    const int N = sizeof(pairs) / sizeof(pairs[0]);
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i){
        const int& key = pairs[i].first;
        const int value = pairs[i].second;
        hash[key].push_back(value);
    }
    display(hash);
}

void display (std::map <int, std::vector<int> > hash)
{
    std::cout << "\tTotal size: " << hash.size() << std::endl; /* Output the size */
    /* Create an iterator, much like vector iterators */
    std::map <int, std::vector<int> >::iterator it;
    for (it = hash.begin(); it != hash.end(); it++){
        /* Output first (which is index) and second (which is the element) */

        const int& key = it->first ;
        std::cout << "key: " << key << "  values: ";

        const std::vector<int>& values = it->second ;
        for(std::size_t i = 0; i < values.size(); ++i)
            std::cout << values[i] << ' ';
        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    std::cout << std::endl; /* Print a new line */
}
```

Comment: In the part of the code `std::make_pair(pairs[foo[i]] , i);` this is essentially doing nothing as the function `make_pair` returns a new object pair created from the two parameters, which isn't being received. As a result your array of pairs `const std::pair<int, int> pairs[size];` will contain values of 0 for every `pair[].first` and `pair[].second`. This in turn, will affect the `for` loop below, as every `int& key` will be 0 and every `value` 0 as well.

Answer (score 2):

By changing:

```
const std::pair<int, int> pairs[size];
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        std::make_pair(pairs[foo[i]] , i);
    }
```

To:

```
std::pair<int, int> pairs[size];
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        pairs[i] = std::make_pair(foo[i] , i);
    }
```

Should fix the initial problem.

Note: I removed const so that the pair values could be modified, else they would all stay (0,0).

Answer (score 1):

The STL map is intended to be used when each key has a unique value.  Rather than using a vector to hold multiple results, it would be much easier to use a multimap.  I have modified your code to demonstrates its usage.  This code requires c++11, but even if you are using an older compiler a multimap can still be used.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <map>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand ((unsigned int)time(NULL));

    //create array for testing
    constexpr int size = 15;
    int foo[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        foo[i] = ((double)rand() * 10 / (double)RAND_MAX + 1);
    }

    //print array:
    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        cout << foo[i] << endl;
    }

    //Find pairs in an array whose sum is equal to ten using hash map
    multimap<int, pair<int, int>> sums;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i+1; j < size; j++)
        {
            int sum = foo[i]+foo[j];
            sums.insert(make_pair(sum, make_pair(foo[i], foo[j])));
        }
    }

    // Print the pairs that sum to 10.
    const auto from = sums.lower_bound(10);
    const auto to = sums.upper_bound(10);
    for (auto i = from; i != to; i++)
    {
        cout << i->second.first << " + " << i->second.second << " = " << i->first << endl;
    }
}
```